# Adding a Select All row into ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

This is my `CustomObdRowAdapter.java`
I added a "Select All" row at the top, when the user chooses it, all items in current listView should be checked, but how should I implement it in my customized row adapter?

```
private class ViewHolder{
    CheckBox name;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater settingInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = settingInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


}else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                RowCheckbox rowCommandCheckbox = (RowCheckbox) cb.getTag();

                if (cb.getText() == ifAllSelectStr){
                    if (cb.isChecked()){          
                       // Select all items in this listView
                    }else{
                       // Unselect all items in this listView
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// select all
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    list.setItemChecked(i, true);
}

// unselect all
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    list.setItemChecked(i, false);
}
```

you may need to call this from outside the adapter

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: this is in my customRowAdapter, how do i initialize "list"?

Comment: I still don't know how to refer the current list in your example

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean isAllTrue=false;
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder = null;
LayoutInflater settingInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = settingInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,  false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    }
else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            RowCheckbox rowCommandCheckbox = (RowCheckbox) cb.getTag();

            if (cb.getText() == ifAllSelectStr){
                if (cb.isChecked()){          
         isAllTrue=true;
      // Select all items in this listView
                }else{
               isAllTrue=false;
                   // Unselect all items in this listView
                    }
               notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
}
```

convertView.setTag(holder);//always put this setting tag outside of if else         //of tag
    holder.name.setChecked(isAllTrue);
  }//end of getView Function

In above code their are two things first is to change setting tag of viewholder to view and place it at the end of function before returning convertView and second create boolean for allTrue checked and when all item selected click listner call then notify adopter to redraw.